# Table is not created again when removed magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

I have a module that creates a table. I removed that table and also removed the entry of that module in "setup_module" too.And after doing all that on page refresh it is not creating the table again. And I again run setup upgrade command. I have flushed the cache, done static content deploy and tried disabling and again enabling the module, but still it is not creating the table in magento 2.

Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong here.

Thanks

Comment: Check your installer script

Comment: My installer script is good it was creating the table previously so i don't think there is any problem on that

Comment: Is there anything that you can suggest of ?

Comment: if it was created table then check in your database if table is already available?

Comment: I have removed that table and entry on  "setup_module" table. and now the table is not created, i have checked that.

Comment: You can try to disable then enable module again with Magento cli command

Answer (score 0):

1. Change or increase the `setup_version="1.0.0"` in your module.xml file, run setup upgrade once again and check.

For example

```
setup_version="1.0.0"

replace 

setup_version="1.1.0"
```

2. Then check the module entry in your `setup_module` table.
3. Still facing same issues, feel free to provide the code in the question.

Comment: I don't want to implement upgrade script here, its not the case of upgrade. The script is not changed i only wanted to check if i removed the table and removed the entry from "setup_module" it should generate new table right? also changing the module version and upgrade script doesn't work

Comment: @ aton1004 okay, can you provide the module code.

Answer (score 0):

Remove your module from `root/app/etc/config.xml`, if available and then run upgrade setup or compile.

You can also try this.

```
bin/magento module:uninstall {NameSpace_Module} --backup-code --backup-media --backup-db
```

let me know if not work.

Comment: Yes i have done that too but no luck.

Comment: first try this `bin/magento module:uninstall {NameSpace_Module} --backup-code --backup-media --backup-db`  in your terminal and then run setup upgrade.